# Проблема с автозаполнением в инпуте

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

Здравствуйте друзья. Имеется инпут

```
<input type="text" name="incoming_sender" id="incoming_sender" class="form-control">
```

Имеется JS код

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#incoming_sender" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'autocomplete.php'
    });
  });
</script>
```

И PHP файл `autocomplete.php` который генерирует варианты для автозаполнения инпута со следующим содержанием :

```
require_once ('includes/connect.php') ;

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM usertbl") or die(mysqli_error());            

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
  $data[] = $row['full_name'];
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Варианты для автозаполнения инпута с именами отправителей берутся из БД. Но проблема в том, что когда пользователь начинает ввод букв или символов в инпут, там отображаются все данные из БД, а не только те в которых есть совпадение с веденным символом. Например из базы вытаскиваются имена 'Сергей', 'Алексей'. Если ввести какую-нибудь цифру, знак препинания или буквы, которых нет в именах, то он все равно отображает все имена. Как это исправить ?

PS: Такой вариант работает без проблем:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#incoming_sender").autocomplete({
      source: [
        "Сергей",
        "Алексей",
        "Игорь",
      ],
      minLength: 1
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Интересно будет глянуть на source: [] когда получаете из базы, как заполняете source ?

Comment: Работает всё правильно. Он показывает все записи из базы данных, так как в запросе вы не учитываете то, что ввёл пользователь. В запросе вам надо сравнивать `full_name` со значением `$_GET['term']`

Comment: Добавил вот это : $term=$_GET["incoming_sender"];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE full_name like '%".$term."%'") теперь вообще не работает...или есть другой вариант сравнивать ?

Comment: @AlexStassov, `$term=$_GET["term"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем файле `autocomplete.php` в запросе нужно учитывать то, что пользователь уже ввёл:

```
require_once ('includes/connect.php') ;
$term = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['term']);
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usertbl WHERE full_name LIKE '%".$term."%'") or die(mysqli_error());          

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data[] = $row['full_name'];
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Спасибо , Pyramidhead, всё работает а главное с разьяснением !